# How to convert a string to integer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, casting, type-conversion

In my application, am having a **TextBox named "Login"**, which stores the login time of an empoloyee. Now I just want to convert this string and store the hours and minutes seperately in 2 different Integer variables. Ex:

```
Login.text="12:40 PM"; // 12:40 PM is system generated time
int HRS=12;
int MINS=40;
```

I have tried the following code snippet:

```
string log = Login.Text;
char[] mychar = {'A','M','P'};
int workhrs = Convert.ToInt32(System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HH"));
int logtime = Convert.ToInt32(log.TrimEnd(mychar));
```

Comment: Look at `Int32.Parse` and `Int32.TryParse`

Comment: The user types in `"12:40 PM"`?

Comment: @Jodrell Looks like a time entering screen where users can enter sign in/out times.

Comment: first http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/w2sa9yss.aspx, then http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.hour.aspx then http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minute.aspx.

Comment: Is it user-entered or does it come from a system?

Comment: @Yahya, its not clear from the question.

Comment: @GrantWinney, its not clear from the question.

Comment: Thnk u for ur support guys... I got the answer from @bema. Kindly make a note of it...friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this with simple splitting:

```
string s = "12:40 PM";
int HRS= Convert.ToInt32(s.Split(':')[0]);
int MINS= Convert.ToInt32(s.Split(':')[1].Split(' ')[0]);
```

or you use the DateTime.ParseExact() Method like:

```
string s = "12:40 PM";
DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(s,"hh:mm tt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
int HRS = time.Hour;
int MINS= time.Minute;
```

Answer (score 7):

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(text,"hh:mm tt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
int h = dt.Hour;
int m = dt.Minute;
```

Comment: Since we're talking about time, this seems more appropriate than a simple int.tryparse of substrings

Answer (score 1):

```
string StringWithNumberIn = "42";
int SomeValue = Convert.ToInt32(StringWithNumberIn);
```

Alternatively you can use `Int32.TryParse` which won't throw an exception if the value in the string isn't actually a valid int.

Answer (score 0):

You have many choices. Among them, Int32.Parse() And Convert.ToInt32()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, how is your string rendered and is it culture invariant?

```
var myDate = DateTime.Parse(Login.Text);
int HRS = myDate.Hour;
int MINS = myDate.Minute;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the text to a DateTime object, then extract from there.

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Parse(Login.Text);
int minute = time.Minute;
int hour = time.Hour;
```

Answer (score 0):

A common problem with DateTime.Parse() is that people only provide one format, which leads to some not so obvious failures because the example only has one time in it.  For instance, in all the previously posted examples the hour was specified as "hh" which works great for the "12" that the original author posted, but fails if the hour is a single digit like "8" (to succeed with "hh" it would have to be "08" instead).  If you change to "h" then "8" would be accepted, but then "12" would fail!  The answer is to create an **array** of allowed formats and pass that in to Parse().  The following code will work for most time entries, including military time:

```
string s = "8:40 PM"; // or from your login box

DateTime time;
string[] formats = {"h:mm tt", "hh:mm tt", "H:mm", "HH:mm"};
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(s, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out time))
{
    int HRS = time.Hour;
    int MINS = time.Minute;

    Console.WriteLine("HRS = " + HRS.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("MINS = " + MINS.ToString());
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid time format!");
}
```